# Replace multiple text values in a single file

Tags: python, python-3.x, router

Python 3 - attempt at Cisco Router deployment script.
I am attempting to replace multiple text values in a input value of 'router-input.txt'.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to replace multiple values in a single file.  At the end of running the below code, only the last value IOSOLD is entered.

```
import fileinput

HOSTNAME = input("Hostname: ")
IOSCURRENT = input("Current IOS image: ")
IOSOLD = input("Old IOS image: ")


f = open("router-input.txt",'r')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()

newdata = filedata.replace("$HOSTNAME", HOSTNAME )
newdata = filedata.replace("$IOSCURRENT", IOSCURRENT )
newdata = filedata.replace("$IOSOLD", IOSOLD )


f = open('output.txt','w')
f.write(newdata)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the file and keeping it in the memory can be very inefficient if the file is too large. I would probably do something like this

```
search_replace_dict = {
    "$HOSTNAME": 'HOSTNAME',
    "$IOSCURRENT": 'IOSCURRENT',
    "$IOSOLD": 'IOSOLD'}

with open("router-input.txt") as input_file, open('output.txt','w') as output_file:
    for each_line in input_file:
        for key, value in search_replace_dict.items():
            each_line = each_line.replace(key, value)
        output_file.write(each_line)
```

Comment: I am able to replace the HOSTNAME value, but the other two are not replaced.  Does this require a loop or some kind?

Comment: ohh yeah sorry just fixed the answer

Comment: I receive the following output and a blank output.txt - AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: Sorry I forgot you were doing this in Python3 iteritems has been removed I will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

You keep editing `filedata` and saving it in `newdata`. Each time, you're overwriting your previous changes. Try:

```
newdata = filedata.replace("$HOSTNAME", HOSTNAME )
newdata = newdata.replace("$IOSCURRENT", IOSCURRENT )
newdata = newdata.replace("$IOSOLD", IOSOLD )
```

Comment: So I should edit the 'newdata.replace' for all lines?
`newdata = hostname.replace("$HOSTNAME", HOSTNAME )
newdata = ioscurrent.replace("$IOSCURRENT", IOSCURRENT )
newdata = iosold.replace("$IOSOLD", IOSOLD )`

Comment: Yes... if you mean there are lines that were omitted that do the same thing... `str.replace` doesn't edit the string it operates on, it returns a new string instead.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way?  Possibly through a loop?  I would expect to have 30ish values to replace in a single file.

Comment: Yeah, there's definitely an easier way, probably through a loop. Maybe using a dictionary...